# Android - Generic Enum<?> abstract declaration does not fit with enum definition in extended class

Tags: android, generics, android-fragments, enums

I've moved some functions I use with fragments to a base class

```
protected void changeToFragment(Enum<?> label){
    changeToFragment(label, false);
}

protected void changeToFragment(Enum<?> label, boolean addToBackStack){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    if (addToBackStack){
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, getFragmentFromLabel(label), label.toString())
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();

    }
    else{
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, getFragmentFromLabel(label), label.toString())
                .commit();
    }
}

protected abstract Fragment getFragmentFromLabel(Enum<?> label);
```

in extended class I've defined an enum as a reference to my fragments

```
private enum Fragments {    FRAG_1,
                            FRAG_2,
                            FRAG_3
                        }
```

and I've implemented the abstract function as

```
@Override
protected Fragment getFragmentFromLabel(Fragments label){
    switch(label){
        case FRAG_1: return getFragment1();
        case FRAG_2: return getFragment2();
        case FRAG_3: return getFragment3();
    }
    return null;
}
```

the problem is that I've got an error saying: Class XXX must be either be declared abstract or implement abstract method *getFragmentFromLabel(Enum label)* in FragmentBaseActivity

Why getFragmentFromLabel(Fragments label) does not fulfill this requirement?

Comment: Would changing the method signature from `...(Fragments label)` to `...(Enum<?> label)` fix your issue? Then cast the enum to the type you need?

Comment: Yeap! It is working with that change and this cast switch((Fragments)label) Thank you !!, but ... in this way method is accepting any kind of enum, could I restrict the method in children class to accept only Fragments enum type ?

Comment: Yea I'll make an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is caused by your method signature. The base class' abstract method's signature is `...(Enum<?> label)` so that's what it expects for the subclass. It doesn't recognize that you're overriding that method since the signature is different. Changing `...(Fragments label)` to `...(Enum<?> label)` will show that you're now overriding the abstract method, thus fixing the error.

This leaves you with the issue of restricting the accepted enum passed in. You could accomplish this by checking the type... e.g.

```
@Override
protected Fragment getFragmentFromLabel(Enum<?> label){
if(label instanceof Fragments){
  switch(label){
    case FRAG_1: return getFragment1();
    case FRAG_2: return getFragment2();
    case FRAG_3: return getFragment3();
  }
}
return null;
}
```

There might be a better way to accomplish this, hopefully it helps

Comment: thats nice, I wonder where there is a method to get code auto-completation working in Android Studio when using this method, in such a way that only Fragments enum is detected